# Encountering TypeError despite following step by step in vega-lite tutorial

Tags: javascript, vega-lite

I followed the tutorial for Vega-Lite step by step but still encountered a TypeError in my vegaEmbed method call

I tried switching from vl.Embed to vegaEmbed, but vl.Embed was undefined and vegaEmbed returned a TypeError.

My html has a div tag with id "vis". The following code was in my script.js file linked to the html.

```
// Vega lite bar chart

const VLSPEC = {
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
    "data":{
      "values":[
        {"a": "C", "b": 2},
        {"a": "C", "b": 7},
        {"a": "C", "b": 4},
        {"a": "D", "b": 1},
        {"a": "D", "b": 2},
        {"a": "D", "b": 6},
        {"a": "E", "b": 8},
        {"a": "E", "b": 4},
        {"a": "E", "b": 7}
      ]
    },
    "mark":"bar",
    "encoding": {
      "y":{"field":"a","type":"nominal"},
      "x":{"field":"b","type": "quantitative",       "aggregate":"average", "axis":{"title": "B mean"}} 
      }

  };

vegaEmbed('#vis',VLSPEC);
```

I expected the bar chart to be plotted (as in https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/site/demo.html), but instead received no visual output but a TypeError in js console.

```
vega-embed@4.2.0:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

    at new ve (vega-embed@4.2.0:1)

    at vega-embed@4.2.0:1

    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

    at vega-embed@4.2.0:1

    at new Promise (<anonymous>)

    at D (vega-embed@4.2.0:1)

    at je (vega-embed@4.2.0:1)

    at Ne (vega-embed@4.2.0:1)

    at script.js:26
```

Answer (score 1):

You refer to a DOM elemend with ID `"#vis"`, and the error indicates that this DOM element is undefined. You should execute this javascript in the context of an HTML page that has the following element:

```
<div id="vis"></div>
```

and then the embed call should work.

You can see this in action in the page source of https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/site/demo.html.

Comment: Hmmmm I have had ``` <div id='vis'>
    </div> ``` in my html code but the error has been showing all this while

Comment: The element must exist at the time the script is run. Make certain you're executing the script after creating the div element.

Comment: Oh!! I added defer attr to my script tag and it worked, thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: @DonovanChua, please accept answers that solve your problem.